# where is located the implementation of getaddressutxos method of litecoin rpc

Tags: json-rpc, litecoin

Hi I have started to play with litecoin node making queries via rpc using litecoin-cli. There are some methods that caught my attention and have something related to "addressindex" these are: 
getaddressbalance
getaddressdeltas
getaddressmempool
getaddresstxids
getaddressutxos

I have looked for them in [github litecoin-project](https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecoin) but I haven't found where is the implementation. Probably I haven't searched in the right place or missed something in the way are called so. Would you help me to find where is the code that implement those methods? Also have you an idea why those methods are not present in Bitcoin? from my perspective are very useful. Thanks in advance

-- UPDATE --

According to [this link](https://bitcore.io/guides/bitcoin/) the methods are already present in Bitcoin. Anyone has an idea at which version they were added? and of course the location

Comment: These methods are not present in Bitcoin Core. Bitcore is a separate project which has an (unmaintained) patch to add them.

Comment: Finally I have found out that those method are part of the project [link] (https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecore-litecoin) and of course @pieter-wuille was 100% right, that's why those methods doesn`t appear on litecoin and bitcoin core  projects.